# How does the processor knows if an instruction came from kernel or not?

Tags: assembly, binary, operating-system, processor

Some instructions are executed by the processor only if the instructions came from kernel. How does the processor knows if an instruction came from kernel or not? I thought that in RAM are 2 different memory locations: one for user-mode, one for kernel-mode. But I think that's not true.

Comment: Check chapter 5.2 in the Intel Processor Manual Volume 3.  Download [is here](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html?iid=tech_vt_tech+64-32_manuals)

Answer (score 0):

Processors have various [protection levels (or "rings")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring). Kernels typically execute in ring 0, user programs in ring 3 (on the x86). Each context switch may change the protection level.